# How to switch screens if I only have one

Tags: display

I installed elementary Loki no problem.
My Zoostorm mini pc thinks it has a laptop screen and 
That my hdmi TV is secondary. There's no way to disable this in bios.

But the install options appeared on my TV and it worked fine. Then i reboot and my TV is secondary display.
As there is no right click option for display settings i cant do anything at all. Anyone got a clue?

I tried windows key plus arrows and it briefly shows a.bit of left screen but pops back.

Tia

Answer (score 1):

You can manage displays (change resolution, choose primary, rotate ...) from System Settings -> Displays. Connect all your available displays and then click on `Detect Displays` (although they should be detected automatically).[image: Displays Plug]
You should now have multiple rectangles, one for each active display. All that's left to do now is to set their preferences, pick a primary one (click on the small star in the top left corner), and disable the ones you do not need (untick `Use This Display`). The rectangles can also be moved around to reflect the real arrangement of your displays.
After setting up everything (in your case, set TV as primary), unplug all the other displays (if any connected) and reboot, just to make sure your settings are preserved.